# HttpUrlConnection to catch SSO auth

Tags: single-sign-on

On a tomcat-7 instance I have ApplicationA, ApplicationB and SSO vavle turned on. Both applications are servlet-based and secured with form security method. 
When I use web browser, SSO works as intended: when I open ApplicationA for the first time, I'm prompted to enter username and login. After I pass login form I can access ApplicatioB without being asked to login.

Now the usecase is: ApplicationA needs to request some content from ApplicationB. So I open ApplicationA in web browser and enter login and password in a login form. After that ApplicationA creates HttpUrlConntection to ApplicationB to get some content but it only gets ApplicationB's login form instead as it is a new request which is not authenticated. 
I expect ApplicationB to be accessed for a programmatic request from ApplicationA without login form because I've logged into SSO in a browser.

Also I need content from ApplicationB as a String in ApplicationA, so I'm not using requestDispatcher.include().

Is it possible? 
Thank you.

What I tried is to set all Cookies (there are things like JSESSIONID and JSESSIONIDSSO) and headers from my browser request to HttpUrlConnection via conn.setRequestProperty() but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enforce Single-Sign-On, the applications must be accessed from same client and not from different clients.

So, it is not possible because you are accessing ApplicationB via HttpUrlConnection within ApplicationA, which is now acting as a new client similar to web-browser client, although both applications are enabled SSO by Tomcat.

Also, setting cookies and headers of web-browser client session in HttpUrlConnection client session will not be honored by Tomcat because HTTP connections are coming from different clients.